# How to update an uploaded image on laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my blade

```php
<a href="{{action('ProduitController@edit', $value->id)}}" class=" btn btn-warning btn-xs">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
</a>

<td><img src='{{ asset('public/images/'.$value->photo) }}' style="width:70px; height:70px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;"></td>
```

This is my contoller

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $prod= \App\Produit::find($id);
    $prod->identification=$request->get('identification');
    $prod->nom=$request->get('nom');
    $prod->description=$request->get('description');
    $prod->quantite=$request->get('quantite');
    $prod->categorie_id=$request->get('categorie_id');
    $prod->prix=$request->get('prix');
    $prod->marque_id=$request->get('marque_id');
    $prod->fournisseur_id=$request->get('fournisseur_id');
    if($request->hasfile('photo'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('photo');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename =time().'.'.$extension;
        $file->move('public/images', $filename);
        $prod->photo =$filename;

    }
    $prod->save();

    Session::flash('message','le produit '.$request->nom.' a été Modifier avec succès');
    return redirect('/produit');

}
```

This is the route for update

```php
Route::resource('ventes','VenteController');
```

If someone has some proposition I will be grateful

Comment: Please give details about errors you get - also you should use a form, and i dont see any file input "photo".

Comment: Are you getting any type if error

Comment: no there is no error, but the image doesn't change Shaielndra , Mtxz no bro i have a form this is the form i will put it now above

Comment: Instead of `$file->move('public/images', $filename);` try `$file->save('public/images', $filename);`

Comment: i tried your solution bro , it still doesn't work (-_-)

Comment: What does `dd($file);` give you after declaration? Upload a very small gif for testing,

Comment: Dimitri Mostrey . i put dd($file); into if condition after $prod->photo =$filename;  but Did not give anything

Comment: Dimitri Mostrey The wonder that the insert works and update now , what can i do in this case i am so confused

Answer (score 0):

checkout your controller catch the 'photo' file by dd it or whatever

if it doesnt have photo file you need to recheck your blade file is it already sending correct parameter or not

if you haven't any issue with insert photo, it should be controller update dont have the photo file, check out your blade to fix the issue, and maybe providing the store controller might help us giving solution

Comment: i catch the photo variable by using dd($file); it contained the photo but did not give anything , and i don't have any problem while inserting image , is there some thing can i change ??